# Italic format usage

Tags: quotation-marks, science, italics

When I was reading some articles, I noticed that they use the *italic* format for some words. Could you please tell me when I have to use it ?

Also, sometimes they used the quotation marks “…” and "...". Is there any difference between them?  and when I have to use them?

Please I need a clear explanation.

Comment: In terms of the former, you'll have to provide an example. Italics can be used for many things including emphasis and noting foreign words. In terms of the latter, it as probably a typographical error or an error in ensuring consistency (assuming you were reading from one source). Some word processors automatically use curly or directional quotes, while others use straight quotes. I don't know of any instance where the type of quote mark mattered beyond style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Italics* note emphasis (HTML  tags are usually implemented as italic); in some systems that did not have multiple typefaces (e.g. typewriters), emphasized text is underlined instead.

Asymmetrical quote marks are just a flourish that some word processors offer; it means exactly the same thing.

Comment: But note that italics are not exactly equivalent to "emphasis". That is one thing they are used for; but not all emphasized text is in italics, and not all italicized text is emphasized. The HTML name is just a name, not a complete explanation of how they are used in typography, and HTML also has presentational markup for italics: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2012/07/on-web-semantics.html, http://learnhtmlwithsong.com/blog/07-1-use-italics-use-emphasis/